# Open a locked file in exlusive mode

Tags: c, file

There is a file which is locked by another process for editing.
Is there any way to open the file in exclusive mode using the C program?

Comment: You should describe the situation where you try to access the file more detailed. What file if locked (DLL/EXE or a file with any data)? Why do you need **exclusive** access? You want probably to do something with the file. What to do (delete, change contain, replace to another file and so on)? Do you need to have access to the same contain of the file or you need to have file on the same place where you need exclusive access? Depend on you answer one can give you a suggestion. What is the process which lock the file (service, GUI application, driver)? Is stop/kill of the process is an option?

Comment: It is data file which is loacked by an application.

Comment: I want to open this file in exclusive mode for some testing purpose,

Comment: If some program locked a file for writing for example, that other program are not able to write to the file. So what you asked is sure not possible. It is the sense of locking. I wrote many programs which access a file and I needed very seldom to lock a file in exclusive mode. What you want to test with the file? Why you need that locking of file from another program will be ignored and from your application do used?

Comment: This question is unanswerable as written because C has no such thing as locking. Please tag your question with whatever environment you're working in (Windows? maybe) and mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, kill the other process.  An OS otherwise of course does not provide a way to allow you to open a locked file, that would utterly defeat the point of supporting locking.

Fwiw, a pretty common mistake is to try to open a file that another process has opened for writing and specifying only read sharing.  Can't work, the other process already gained write access.  You must specify read+write sharing.

Comment: I cannot kill the other process.

Comment: From above comments,I think there is no way to open the locked file in exclusive mode.

Comment: @Pradeep: Do you understand that there are a contradiction in your question? You can not go through the only closed door without opening it or breaking it!